# Why French characters speak in British instead of French accent?

Tags: dialogue, the-day-of-the-jackal

In *[The Day of the Jackal (1973)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069947/)*, plot is about OAS Agents trying to assassinate French president. But none of the French officials like *Minister*, *Lebel* etc speak in french accent, They all speak in British accent.

Well! My question very much similar to this question [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44675/why-do-the-russian-and-german-characters-not-speak-in-their-respective-accents).